# SQLAlchemy: Invalid SQL with load_only, order_by and limit

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgis, geoalchemy2

When running the example below, the following, invalid SQL query is generated:

```
SELECT anon_1.venue_id              AS anon_1_venue_id, 
    St_asbinary(anon_1.venue_location)  AS anon_1_venue_location, 
    St_asbinary(anon_1.anon_2)      AS anon_1_anon_2, 
    label_1.id              AS label_1_id 
FROM    (
    SELECT venue.id AS venue_id, 
               venue.location AS venue_location, 
               venue.location <-> St_geomfromtext(:ST_GeomFromText_1, 
                  :ST_GeomFromText_2) AS anon_2 
    FROM   venue 
    ORDER  BY venue.location <-> St_geomfromtext(:ST_GeomFromText_1, 
                     :ST_GeomFromText_2) 
    LIMIT  :param_1
    ) AS anon_1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    venue_to_label AS venue_to_label_1 
    JOIN label AS label_1 
    ON label_1.id = venue_to_label_1.label_id) 
ON anon_1.venue_id = venue_to_label_1.venue_id 
ORDER  BY anon_1.anon_2
```

The problem is that St_asbinary is applied to anon_1.anon_2. I'd expect the line either not to be generated or at least without the "St_asbinary". I'm pretty sure that this is the fault of GeoAlchemy2. Can anyone comment on that assumption?

*Any idea how to best resolve this issue? It seems pretty fundamental unfortunately. We're trying to use the code in a big project and any help is welcome!*

The (minimal) example below assumes a local PostgreSQL database "tmp" with GIS extension installed.

```
import unittest
from geoalchemy2 import WKTElement, Geometry
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload, relationship, load_only
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = (
    'postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/tmp')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Base = declarative_base()

# many (venue) <-> many (label) mapping table
venue_to_label = Table(
    'venue_to_label', db.metadata,
    Column('venue_id', Integer, ForeignKey('venue.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('label_id', Integer, ForeignKey('label.id'), primary_key=True)
)


class Label(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'label'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)


class Venue(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    labels = relationship(Label, secondary=venue_to_label)
    location = Column(Geometry(geometry_type="POINT"), nullable=False)

db.create_all()


class TestGeoAlchemy2Bug(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_geo_alchemy2_bug(self):
        point = WKTElement("POINT(0 0)")

        query = Venue.query
        query = query.options(joinedload(*['labels']).load_only(*['id']))
        query = query.order_by(Venue.location.distance_centroid(point))
        query = query.limit(10)

        print query
        print query.all()
```

Disclaimer: I've already posted the problem as an issue on the GeoAlchemy2 github page, but haven't gotten any reply there yet (https://github.com/geoalchemy/geoalchemy2/issues/93).

Even some general advice which direction I should be looking is very much appreciated!

Thank you for your help!

---

**Update**

Resolved this for now by creating the "missing" function when the database is created with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION St_asbinary(double precision)
    RETURNS double precision
AS 'select $1;'
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

Still very interested in a proper solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved in the latest release!
https://github.com/geoalchemy/geoalchemy2/issues/93